# my 1990 Ford ranger

Tags: ford, ranger

was driving to take a friend home engine started making kind of a rattling sound then lost power and then the power came back, the gauge wasnt reading that it was running hot, and then it started making the noise and losing power again on his road and as soon as we turned in his driveway the engine stopped and I tried to fire it back up just to see it wouldn't even turn over, I waited almost 1 hour and tried to crank again and it turned over but didn't try to crank, I normally know the problem but I'm lost now

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!